# Exception when using TSQL type "Date" with Mono

Tags: database, t-sql, date, mono

I'm using Mono 2.10.8.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 Server.

I'm using an ADO.net `TableAdapter` to grab data from SQL Server 2008. When I encounter a `Date` column, Mono gives the following error:

> No mapping exists from SqlDbType Date to a known DbType.

I'm not entirely sure what Mono uses for DB access (FreeTDS/etc) so I'm not 100% sure where to even start my search for a solution.

An obvious solution would be to simply change the column in the DB to `DateTime`, but since it is in production I do not have that option.

Has anybody else encountered this error before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your TableAdapter SQL statement, try casting or converting the field being returned as a date to a datetime or, if necessary, to a varchar field with the necessary formatting. You can achieve this by doing the following:

```
Select field1
    , field2
    , CAST(date_field as datetime) as New_datetime_field
    , CONVERT(varchar(10),date_field,101) as New_varchar_field --stored as MM/DD/YYYY string

From Table
```

Doing this will now cause the field returned by the query or stored procedure to be recognized as SQL as a datetime or varchar field. It should then be passed on using the TableAdapter as a datetime or varchar field. Using the convert statement, you can convert a date into any number of formats (see [here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) for more information).